# How to structure a compound conditional with several tests (at least 1 of which is regex)

Tags: regex, bash, shell, if-statement

I searched for this but haven't found an answer to this particular situation. I'm familiar with file tests in shells and with using the [[ ]] syntax to perform regex matching.

Is there a way to combine these two operations in a compound conditional that doesn't require multiple nested ifs?

So far I've tried the following (...and other much crazier variations):

```
if  [   -e ~/.profile   -a   $0 =~ bash         ]; then echo yes ; fi
if  [   -e ~/.profile   -a ( $0 =~ bash )       ]; then echo yes ; fi
if  [   -e ~/.profile   -a [ $0 =~ bash ]       ]; then echo yes ; fi
if [[   -e ~/.profile   -a   $0 =~ bash        ]]; then echo yes ; fi
if [[ ( -e ~/.profile ) -a ( $0 =~ bash )      ]]; then echo yes ; fi

if [ -e ~/.profile -a           $0 =~ bash      ]; then echo yes; fi
if [ -e ~/.profile -a $( [      $0 =~ bash ] )  ]; then echo yes; fi
if [ -e ~/.profile -a   [[      $0 =~ bash ]]   ]; then echo yes; fi
if [ -e ~/.profile -a $([[      $0 =~ bash ]])  ]; then echo yes; fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, when you want to represent a LOGICAL AND between these two statements, you must use && instead of `-a` (which the shell interprets as "does this file exist" file test in double brackets). Also, for the regex to work, the statement must be within `[[ ]]`. What was unknown to me at the time is that even though `-a` changes its meaning in double brackets, the `-e` `-w` `-r` and other file tests don't change their functionality (e.g. it's the same for single or double brackets).

```
if [[ -w ~/.bash_profile && $0 =~ bash  ]]; then ( echo 1 ; echo 2 ) >> .bash_profile
elif [[ -w ~/.profile && <someothercondition> ]]; then
  ( echo 3
    echo 4
    echo 5
  ) >> .profile
fi
```

Comment: The single-bracket test expression syntax uses `-a` and `-o` for "and" and "or" respectively, and does not support regex matching; the double-bracket conditional expression syntax uses `&&` and `||` for "and" and "or", and *does* support regex matching with the `=~` operator. See [BashFAQ #31: What is the difference between `test`, `[` and `[[` ?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031)

Comment: @GordonDavisson I really like the extra explanation and variations given in your link. Really helps give a better understanding of the syntax. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`-a` is treated as an `AND` when using single brackets, eg:

```
$ [ 3 -gt 1 -a 2 -lt 3 ] && echo 'true'
true
```

For double brackets you want to use `&&`, eg:

```
$ [[ 3 -gt 1 && 2 -lt 3 ]] && echo 'true'
true
```

Alternatively you can `&&` to separate tests regardless of whether you're using single or double brackets, eg:

```
$ [ 3 -gt 1 ] && [ 2 -lt 3 ] && echo 'true'
true

$ [[ 3 -gt 1 ]] && [[ 2 -lt 3 ]] && echo 'true'
true

$ [ 3 -gt 1 ] && [[ 2 -lt 3 ]] && echo 'true'
true
```

**NOTE:** same rules apply for `-o` vs `||` (aka `OR`)

Comment: I feel it's important to note that by removing the `if <condition> then; <   > ; fi` syntax as you have by pulling the `&&` outside the brackets, if you wanted to execute a series of commands when the set of tested conditions return true or false, you would be forced to clutter the code with additional `&&` for each statement executed based on the condition. Keeping the `if <condition> then; <   > ; fi` syntax allows one to string a few cmds on the same line separated by `;` or to separate them out on multiple lines without any semicolons to separate the statements.

Comment: Additionally, the if/then syntax allows you.... for a set of conditions that return false.... to then execute another check on several conditions with a subsequent `elif [[ cond1 && cond2 ]]; then `.  This is why I prefer the solution I submitted as an answer. However, I voted up your answer b/c I appreciate the effort to answer the question.